# Request for alternative method suggestions to this Google Sheets formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I wrote this ridiculously long formula (60,000+ characters, shown below) in Google Sheets, and it works perfectly. However, now I want to simplify it, as I'm certain that it's inefficient and could be written - at minimum - more tightly.

Essentially, it's looking at a list of hotel reservations and displaying the rack rate of each individual reservation. It uses several criteria for this:

- **Season** (there are four seasons: Holiday, High, Mid, and Low).
- **Room Type** (there are currently 12 different room classes).
- **Year** (each business year has different date ranges that define its seasons).
- **Day of Week** (the rooms have different rates for weekdays and weekends).

I'm not looking for anyone to voluntarily re-write the formula (or do anything else) for me, but my guess is that I could probably achieve the same (or even better) result if I used some method other than an IFS-AND formula.

My hope is that someone will point me to the better-best method of doing this (pivot tables? lookups? something else?) so that I can go and read the docs for it and then build it on my own. A point in the right direction might help me avoid some unnecessary dead ends.

(Edit) - link to demo sheet: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1weJgCmV_2Hzifb8QoR7I7gMhrAovLs5tXnKqW1ZWuU4/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks!

H.

```
=IFS(
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$4,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$C$8,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$5,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$C$9,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$6,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$C$10,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$7,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$C$11,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$8,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$C$12,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$9,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$C$13,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$10,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$C$14,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$11,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$C$15,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$13,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$C$17,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$14,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$C$18,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$15,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$C$19,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$16,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$C$20,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$4,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$F$8,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$5,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$F$9,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$6,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$F$10,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$7,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$F$11,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$8,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$F$12,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$9,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$F$13,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$10,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$F$14,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$11,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$F$15,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$13,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$F$17,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$14,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$F$18,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$15,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$F$19,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$16,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$F$20,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$4,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$I$8,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$5,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$I$9,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$6,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$I$10,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$7,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$I$11,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$8,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$I$12,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$9,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$I$13,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$10,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$I$14,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$11,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$I$15,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$13,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$I$17,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$14,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$I$18,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$15,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$I$19,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$16,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$I$20,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$4,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$L$8,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$5,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$L$9,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$6,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$L$10,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$7,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$L$11,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$8,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$L$12,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$9,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$L$13,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$10,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$L$14,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$11,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$L$15,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$13,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$L$17,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$14,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$L$18,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$15,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$L$19,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$16,S4=2020,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$L$20,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$4,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$B$8,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$5,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$B$9,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$6,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$B$10,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$7,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$B$11,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$8,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$B$12,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$9,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$B$13,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$10,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$B$14,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$11,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$B$15,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$13,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$B$17,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$14,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$B$18,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$15,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$B$19,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$B$2,Q4=Data!$A$16,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$B$20,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$4,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$E$8,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$5,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$E$9,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$6,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$E$10,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$7,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$E$11,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$8,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$E$12,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$9,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$E$13,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$10,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$E$14,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$11,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$E$15,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$13,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$E$17,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$14,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$E$18,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$15,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$E$19,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$E$2,Q4=Data!$A$16,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$E$20,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$4,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$H$8,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$5,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$H$9,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$6,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$H$10,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$7,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$H$11,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$8,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$H$12,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$9,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$H$13,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$10,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$H$14,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$11,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$H$15,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$13,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$H$17,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$14,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$H$18,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$15,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$H$19,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$H$2,Q4=Data!$A$16,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$H$20,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$4,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$K$8,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$5,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$K$9,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$6,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$K$10,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$7,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$K$11,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$8,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$K$12,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$9,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$K$13,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$10,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$K$14,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$11,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$K$15,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$13,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$K$17,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$14,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$K$18,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$15,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$K$19,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$K$2,Q4=Data!$A$16,S4=2020,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$K$20,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$4,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$P$8,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$5,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$P$9,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$6,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$P$10,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$7,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$P$11,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$8,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$P$12,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$9,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$P$13,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$10,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$P$14,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$11,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$P$15,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$13,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$P$17,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$14,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$P$18,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$15,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$P$19,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$16,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$P$20,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$4,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$S$8,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$5,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$S$9,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$6,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$S$10,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$7,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$S$11,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$8,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$S$12,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$9,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$S$13,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$10,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$S$14,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$11,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$S$15,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$13,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$S$17,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$14,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$S$18,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$15,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$S$19,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$16,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$S$20,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$4,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$V$8,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$5,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$V$9,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$6,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$V$10,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$7,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$V$11,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$8,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$V$12,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$9,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$V$13,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$10,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$V$14,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$11,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$V$15,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$13,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$V$17,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$14,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$V$18,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$15,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$V$19,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$16,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$V$20,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$4,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$Y$8,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$5,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$Y$9,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$6,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$Y$10,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$7,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$Y$11,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$8,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$Y$12,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$9,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$Y$13,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$10,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$Y$14,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$11,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$Y$15,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$13,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$Y$17,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$14,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$Y$18,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$15,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$Y$19,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$16,S4=2021,U4=True), 'Rack Rates'!$Y$20,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$4,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$O$8,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$5,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$O$9,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$6,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$O$10,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$7,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$O$11,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$8,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$O$12,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$9,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$O$13,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$10,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$O$14,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$11,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$O$15,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$13,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$O$17,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$14,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$O$18,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$15,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$O$19,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$O$2,Q4=Data!$A$16,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$O$20,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$4,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$R$8,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$5,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$R$9,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$6,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$R$10,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$7,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$R$11,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$8,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$R$12,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$9,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$R$13,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$10,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$R$14,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$11,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$R$15,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$13,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$R$17,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$14,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$R$18,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$15,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$R$19,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$R$2,Q4=Data!$A$16,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$R$20,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$4,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$U$8,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$5,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$U$9,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$6,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$U$10,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$7,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$U$11,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$8,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$U$12,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$9,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$U$13,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$10,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$U$14,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$11,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$U$15,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$13,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$U$17,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$14,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$U$18,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$15,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$U$19,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$U$2,Q4=Data!$A$16,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$U$20,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$4,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$X$8,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$5,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$X$9,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$6,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$X$10,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$7,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$X$11,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$8,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$X$12,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$9,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$X$13,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$10,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$X$14,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$11,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$X$15,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$13,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$X$17,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$14,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$X$18,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$15,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$X$19,
AND(R4='Rack Rates'!$X$2,Q4=Data!$A$16,S4=2021,U4=False), 'Rack Rates'!$X$20,
AND(R4<>99999), "...")
```

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: IMHO you should add more details like the spreadsheet and sheet structure.

Comment: Added link to demo sheet.

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your Rack Rates data a bit.

Add to your "Rack Rates" technical row which will contain key for further mapping - just adding together your variables (i.e. Low2020FALSE).

Then Use following formula to get required rate

```
=INDEX('Rack Rates'!$A:$Y,
 MATCH(P4,'Rack Rates'!$A:$A,0),
 MATCH(Q4&R4&T4,'Rack Rates'!$A$1:$Y$1,0))
```

You can find it here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_yWM2lNNLkETaLPWcLoHd1bJrCFIdwZMU2NNvlX_qSA/edit#gid=1494847140

Comment: Well, I was hoping that someone would tell me I should be using x method instead of just a formula (pivot tables? lookups? something else?), but perhaps such a thing isn't realistic. I'll except your suggestion for improving my formula, Oleg. Thanks!